# How handling existing Windows-8-Preview questions?

Tags: discussion, windows-8-challenge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What will happen to the Windows-8-Preview tag once Windows 8 goes live?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5167/what-will-happen-to-the-windows-8-preview-tag-once-windows-8-goes-live)

Many questions related to Windows were already asked in the scope of the Windows 8 Release Preview with the tag Windows-8-Preview.

Should these questions be re-tagged or newly created with the correct tag, as the question may not be valid anymore with the final release?

Because with the Windows-8 Challenge several questions have just been copied and will still lead to some copy-paste behavior.

Comment: @Oliver I'm not sure if this is quite an exact dupe. We've made a decision on what to do with the flag, but this question is asking whether existing questions should be fixed with the correct tag. Which I think is the right direction to go.

Comment: if it's been copied, please flag it as dupes.