# Deprecate product version preview tags - just use new version tag straight away

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tags, tag-cleanup-request, preview

*(Related to [What will happen to the Windows-8-Preview tag once Windows 8 goes live?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5167/what-will-happen-to-the-windows-8-preview-tag-once-windows-8-goes-live))*

I notice [windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) is synonymous with [windows-10-preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-preview). What's the rationale here?

In theory having the two separate tags would allow us to later filter out questions that arose during the technical preview. But that won't be the case if one's a synonym of the other.

On the other hand, if it's not useful to have this distinction, [windows-10-preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-preview) seems pointless, and we should just use [windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10).

With the benefit of hindsight, I think in future we ought to deprecate creation/use of "product version preview" tags, and instead simply create and use a tag for the upcoming version straight away.

Comment: I disagree; there are numerous cases of problems with both Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 that were not problems or in some cases were removed in the final version.

Comment: Even if Microsoft disables Win 10 Preview, there will be users who keep it working and don't want to migrate to Win 10.  Will Win 10 Preview questions (related to Preview-specific problems), still be on-topic after Win 10 is released?  If so, that would suggest a need to retain the Preview tag.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think we _are_ disagreeing. My point is that pre-RTM, in many cases we can't know which of those categories a problem is in, so we can't yet tag it in a way which makes that distinction. And since no one will (post-RTM) review _every_ Windows X question, research the problem to find whether the issue still applies post-RTM, and tag the question accordingly, the preview tag is of dubious benefit. The best we can hope for is for Windows X questions to be annotated, on a case-by-case basis, as users encounter them later and can comment "this is no longer an issue post-RTM" etc.

Comment: @fixer1234 please see my last comment to Ramhound, which is relevant to your point too.

Comment: The thing is Windows Preview will even exist after July 29, so I only agree, partially at this point.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Windows 8, it was enough to break the synonym, and manually close or retag questions based on relevance.

However, [we have a new problem in with Windows 10](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9551/what-to-do-about-the-windows-insider-program) - the insider program is ongoing. That makes what to do about the preview tag less clear.

I don't think we can have a general solution to this problem, it would need to be taken on a case-by-case basis.